# How to modernize: database object as an associative array throughout application

Tags: oop, architecture

I'm a relatively new programmer, so hopefully I'm using the correct terminology; if something isn't clear, please do let me know. In a very large legacy application, we have a `users` database:

```
users
id       type      name
1        3         Jeff
2        2         Holly
3        4         Tyler
```

Throughout most of the application, a user's info is gotten as an associative array. We happen to use php, but I would think this problem applies to any language.

**The Problem**

Throughout the app we have hundreds upon hundreds of getting a row from `users` as an associative array, `$user['type']` and using this to do some business logic; now we want to make a change to how `type` works, and it is extremely difficult to even FIND all of the places this field is used. The word "type" is used in comments, other variables, etc.

**The Question**

Is this one of the reasons for OOP? Is OOP the primary solution to us not causing more of this problem/fixing it, or is there some other way? It seems that if instead of an associative array, we had a user object and were doing a `$type = $user->getType();` it would be much easier for us to use our IDE to find all usages of `->getType()`

Answer (score 0):

Abstraction solves this type of problem. For example, imagine that a user is defined as having a username and an email address, both of data type 'string'. If these two properties were accidentally switched in their assignments, the compiler would not reject this, and the resulting bug would only surface when the application is running.

However, if username and email address are abstracted as 'Username' and 'EmailAddress', respectively, one would have to assign values of the correct types in order for the compiler to accept the code.

Abstraction can be done in programming paradigms other than OO, but typically OO lends itself better to it because, well, abstracting concepts is basically thinking in terms of objects.

As for your particular case, it is also solved with abstraction. Instead of working with an 'array of values' representing a user, you would instead be working with an abstraction of a user, implemented as a class 'User' with an 'id' property, a 'type' property, and a 'name' property. When you pass that abstraction (or object, when implemented in an OOP language), there is no ambiguity about what it represents and what its physical definition is (that is, 'id' of type int, 'type' of type int, 'name' of type string).

Some people say that strong typing solves this problem, but that is not necessarily true if the abstraction is not enforced. Think back to the example of inverting username and email address: even if the compiler enforces the check that username is a string and email address is a string, it still cannot detect that you have switched the two when assigning  their values.

Some also say that only OO languages solve this problem. Again, this is not true: as long as the language supports abstraction and the programmer puts in the work, the problem can be avoided. For example, `struct` in C can do this--which is also an argument for the claim that one can do OOP with a non-OOP language.

Having said all this, in practice, you would weigh the benefit of how much abstraction you need versus the effort required to do so. For example, one would not necessarily abstract username and email address for the example above because modern IDEs provide enough hints to help reduce such potential mistakes.